# Spring security pass SecurityExpressionRoot to custom method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to pass `SecurityExpressionRoot` class, which i can access inside `@PreAuthorise()` annotation, to my custom `checkAccess()` method which checks access to specific method, using some logic based on authorities, roles and a additional variables that i pass to this method.
Inside `@PreAuthorise()` I can access methods from `SecurityExpressionRoot`, for example. `hasAuthority()`

Is there any way to do that?

Controller:

```
public class TestController {

    private final PreAuthorizeChecker preAuthorizeChecker;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(PreAuthorizeChecker preAuthorizeChecker) {
        this.preAuthorizeChecker = preAuthorizeChecker;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    @PreAuthorize("@preAuthorizeChecker.checkAccess(/*SecurityExpressionRoot.getSomehow()*/)")    //How to obtain SecurityExpressionRoot instance?
    public ResponseEntity<Void> get() {
        return;
    }
```

PreAuthorizeChecker:

```
@Component
public class PreAuthorizeChecker {

    @Autowired
    public PreAuthorizeChecker() {
    }

    public boolean checkAccess(SecurityExpressionRoot securityExpressionRoot) {
        //do sth with securityExpressionRoot
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find that part 5 of this blog, [A Custom Security Expression with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression), on Baelding.com helpful. The author suggests extending SecurityExpressionRoot and adding your custom method to the new class like this:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

       public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
            super(authentication);
       }

       public boolean checkAccess() {
            //do sth with securityExpressionRoot
            return true;
       }

...
}
```

Then you will need to inject that new class into the expression handler like this:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

      private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

      @Override
      protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
           CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
           root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
           root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
           root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
           return root;
      }
}
```

Finally, you just need to create the expression handler in your security config like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Then your new expression should be available:

```
  @PreAuthorize("checkAccess()")
  public ResponseEntity<Void> get() {
      return;
  }
```